# Django/Apache2 Context variables not availables

Tags: django, django-templates, apache2.4

i'm a Django/Apache novice.
following lots of tutorial i was able to build my small app for Home Domotic.
Nevertheless i'm now experiencing a new problem.

In Django app i have some templates that i call with views passing some CONTEXT variables.
When i load the page with the internal Django Web Server (RUNWEBSERVER) the variables values are printed on the screen, but when i load the page with Apache the variables values are missing.

Can somebody help me ?

Thank you.
Ciao.
g

Comment: By "screen" do you mean rendered page or console window? Please update your question and add some details. Apache config, view and template code would be helpful.

Comment: By screen i want to say rendered page.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!! 
Is seems that Apache need a restart before reading python code modify.
Thanks all. Ciao.